# Swift Struct-based Factory Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, swift, factory-method, abstract-factory

**Edit**: I added another configuration vector to CardView, a `size` attribute, which may be `.small` or `.medium`. As such, I had to refactor the design to create several descendent protocols of `CardView` for each attribute, and several concrete structs corresponding to each possible combinations of size and style. Here is the updated design:

```
// MARK: Example
let example: some View = CardView2Factory.create(
    colors: (.red, .blue),
    name: "My Birthday",
    range: .init(start: Date(), duration: 0),
    configuration: (size: .small, style: .inverted)
)

// MARK: Factory

/// A Factory class used to create a customized `CardView`
class CardView2Factory {
    enum Size {
        case small, medium
    }
    
    enum Style {
        case plain, inverted
    }
    
    private init() {}
    
    /// Creates a new CardView.
    ///
    /// The unique combination of the configuration's `size` and `style` attributes correspond one-to-one with an internal View struct conforming to `CardView`
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - colors: the tuple of colors of an Event, used to form the stops of the gradient
    ///   - name: the name of an Event
    ///   - range: the range of an Event
    ///   - configuration: a configuration specifying the size and style attributes of the View
    ///
    /// - Returns: A configuration-dependent CardView expressed as a View
    @ViewBuilder
    static func create(colors: (Color, Color), name: String, range: DateInterval, configuration: (size: Size, style: Style)) -> some View {
        switch configuration {
        case (.small, .plain):
            SmallPlainCardView2(colors: colors, name: name, range: range)
            
        case (.small, .inverted):
            SmallInvertedCardView2(colors: colors, name: name, range: range)
            
        case (.medium, .plain):
            MediumPlainCardView2(colors: colors, name: name, range: range)
            
        case (.medium, .inverted):
            MediumInvertedCardView2(colors: colors, name: name, range: range)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Main Protocol

protocol CardView2: View {
    associatedtype Accent: ShapeStyle & View
    associatedtype Background: ShapeStyle
    
    var colors: (Color, Color) { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var range: DateInterval { get }
    
    var headerTextColor: Color { get }
    var accent: Accent { get }
    var background: Background { get }
}

// MARK: Size Protocols

extension CardView2 {
    fileprivate var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    }
    
    fileprivate var dateComponentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter {
    }
        
    fileprivate var mainText: Text {
    }
    
    fileprivate var shape: some Shape {
    }
    
    fileprivate var text: some View {
    }
}

protocol SmallCardView2: CardView2 {
}

extension SmallCardView2 {
    var body: some View {
        ViewA(colors, name, range, accent, etc...)
    }
}

protocol MediumCardView2: CardView2 {
}

extension MediumCardView2 {
    var body: some View {
        ViewB(colors, name, range, accent, etc...)
    }
}

// MARK: Style Protocols

protocol PlainCardView2: CardView2 {
}

extension PlainCardView2 {
    var headerTextColor: Color {
    }
    
    var accent: LinearGradient {
    }
    
    var background: Color {
    }
}

protocol InvertedCardView2: CardView2 {
}

extension InvertedCardView2 {
    var headerTextColor: Color {
    }
    
    var accent: Color {
    }
    
    var background: LinearGradient {
    }
}

// MARK: Implementation

fileprivate struct SmallPlainCardView2: SmallCardView2, PlainCardView2 {
    let colors: (Color, Color)
    let name: String
    let range: DateInterval
}

fileprivate struct SmallInvertedCardView2: SmallCardView2, InvertedCardView2 {
    let colors: (Color, Color)
    let name: String
    let range: DateInterval
}

fileprivate struct MediumPlainCardView2: MediumCardView2, PlainCardView2 {
    let colors: (Color, Color)
    let name: String
    let range: DateInterval
}

fileprivate struct MediumInvertedCardView2: MediumCardView2, InvertedCardView2 {
    let colors: (Color, Color)
    let name: String
    let range: DateInterval
}
```

and here is the corresponding class diagram (albeit in Java):

[image: class diagram]

---

Using SwiftUI, I have multiple different Views which only differ in some style-based variables. So, I created a Protocol `CardView` to condense all the similarities in one entity. The Protocol itself inherits from `View` and implements most of the functionality including `var body`. It also has several `associatedtype`s.

I want the client to be able to retrieve an instance of a struct that conforms to this Protocol by simply selecting a case from an enum `Style`. I decided to use the Factory pattern to do so. However, I learned that Protocols can't have static functions themselves so I had to create a new `CardViewFactory` class that had a static `create` method with a `style: Style` parameter. Another concession I had to make was that this factory method returned `some View` and not a `CardView` as would have been preferred, due to its `associatedtype` requirements.

I'm looking for any feedback on the design of my hierarchy and implementation of the Factory pattern. Thanks!

**CardViewFactory**

```
class CardViewFactory {
    enum Style {
        case plain, inverted
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder static func create(name: String, range: DateInterval, colors: (Color, Color), style: Style) -> some View {
        switch style {
        case .plain:
            CardViewA(colors: colors, name: name, range: range)
            
        case .inverted:
            CardViewB(colors: colors, name: name, range: range)
        }
    }
}
```

**CardView**

```
protocol CardView: View {
    associatedtype Accent: ShapeStyle & View
    associatedtype Background: ShapeStyle
    
    var colors: (Color, Color) { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var range: DateInterval { get }
    
    var headerTextColor: Color { get }
    var accent: Accent { get }
    var background: Background { get }
}

extension CardView {
    var body: some View {
         EmptyView() // for example
    }
}
```

**Example Implementation**

```
struct CardViewA: CardView {
    let colors: (Color, Color)
    let name: String
    let range: DateInterval
    
    let headerTextColor: Color = .black
    
    var accent: LinearGradient {
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: .init(colors: [colors.0, colors.1]),
            startPoint: .topTrailing,
            endPoint: .bottomLeading
        )
    }
    
    let background: Color = .white
}
```